# In termux android ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied?

Tags: android, ls

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDpoI.jpg)

'''ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied'''

Comment: If you're running Android 11+, you don't have unrestricted access to the `android/data` directory in shared storage and `termux` can't grant that access.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your errors and code as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Settings → Apps → All Apps → Termux → Permissions*. Grant the permission to access the storage. After that, you shouldn't get this error for shared storage.

Answer (score 1):

beside the instruction other people mentioned:

- Go to Settings → Apps → All Apps → Termux → Permissions. Grant the permission to access the storage. After that, you shouldn't get this error for shared storage.
- run termux-setup-storage

you may also need to do it as a root user.

Comment: This answer doesn't add any new information to a **ten month old** post.
Instead you've practically copy-pasted previous answers

Answer (score -1):

Run

```
termux-setup-storage
```

And reset Termux

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).